# Retrofit not parsing JSONObject

Tags: android, parsing, retrofit, json

A successful login returns the following `JSONObject` from a server:

```
{"success":true,"message":"Sign in success.","response_data":{"user_id":"24", "email_id":"user@gmail.com", "secret_code": "You did it!"}}
```

I want to put the `response_data` info into my `User` object. I used to do something like this:

```
String getResponse = jsonObject.getString("response_data");

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .disableHtmlEscaping()
        .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE)
        .setPrettyPrinting()
        .serializeNulls()
        .create();

//All the data in the `response_data` is initialized in `User`
User user = gson.fromJson(getResponse, User.class);
```

Now I tried doing the same in retrofit:

Initializing RestAdapter + Interface:

```
public class ApiClient {
    private static RetrofitService sRetrofitService;

    public static RetrofitService getRetrofitApiClient() {
        if (sRetrofitService == null) {
            RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                    .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                    .setEndpoint("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/")
                    .build();

            sRetrofitService = restAdapter.create(RetrofitService.class);
        }

        return sRetrofitService;
    }

    public interface RetrofitService {

        @FormUrlEncoded
        @POST("/login")
        public void login(@Field("email_id") String emailId, @Field ("password") String password, 
                          Callback <User> callback);                                                                    
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
  ApiClient.getRetrofitApiClient().login(email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString(),       
      new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void success(User user, Response response) {
                User user1 = user; //null
                Toast.makeText(this, "user is: "+user1.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

User:

```
public class User {

    private String userId;
    private String emailId;
    private String code;

    public User() {

    }

    ... getters
    ... setters
}
```

The `Retrofit` code in `MainActivity` works and I get this response in my `log`:

```
{"success":true,"message":"Sign in success.","response_data":{"user_id":"24", "email_id":"user@gmail.com", "secret_code": "You did it!"}}
```

However it doesn't parse the `response_data` into my `User` object.

How do I fix this?

Comment: no, just a typo unfortunately... i'll fix that. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a response object

```
public class UserResponse {
  private User responseData;
  private String message;
  private boolean success;
}
```

And change your callback to return a UserResponse

```
public interface RetrofitService {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/login")
    public void login(@Field("email_id") String emailId, @Field ("password") String password, 
                      Callback <UserResponse> callback);                                                                    
}
```

*NOTE:* You will also need to create your custom Gson instance and aplly that to the rest adapter.

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = RestAdapter.Builder()
  .setEndpoint("xxx")
  .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
  .build()
```

Comment: I was only using Gson before Retrofit. Isn't Gson automatically integrated into Retrofit? Why would I need to declare a custom Gson instance?

Comment: @user2456977 You add a converter so you can configure options such as the field naming policy. You don't have to if you are using all of the defaults.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,

```
setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE);
```

You want

```
setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
```

as that's how your fields are named. (e.g. `response_data`)

Then, your `User` class does not represent the answer from your service. Create a model class that mimics the structure of your json object. (as suggested by cyroxis).

Finally, the naming of your java members is inconsistent with the naming of your json fields (e.g. `secret_code` vs `code` in User). Either fix this, or use `@SerializedName` to explicitly match a json field to a java field.

Comment: I was only using Gson before Retrofit. Isn't Gson automatically integrated into Retrofit? Why would I need to declare a custom Gson instance?  And thanks for pointing out the inconsistencies. I will fix them

Comment: you need to customize your gson instance if your json fields don't match your java fields. Typically when json uses snake case and java uses camel case.

Comment: also, retrofit does not do any interpretation for you. You tell it to put that data into a User instance, it tries to do just that. And your data does not represent a User. It represents an object that contains a field `response_data` that is the data for a User.

Answer (score 1):

If you do two things it might fix your problem:

1. Change your FieldNamingPolicy on your GSON Builder to use [LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/FieldNamingPolicy.html#LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
2. Change the scope of your variables in UserResponse and User to public (this might not be required)

Comment: I was only using Gson before Retrofit. Isn't Gson automatically integrated into Retrofit? Why would I need to declare a custom Gson instance?